# ASP.NET MVC NavBar does not display unless inspecting elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've recently started doing some experimenting to gain experience with ASP.NET MVC. My commercial experience has been with WinForms, so it's proving a challenge (but interesting)

My starting point has been to use a guide from Microsoft:
[MVC Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/)
The guide is written with ASP.NET Core in mind, however, I'm using .NET 4.5. I've found some differences with the way HML is generated (HttpUtility.HtmlEncode) but nothing too major.

I've created an ASP.NET MVC5 project and started to play around with adding new controllers. The strange thing I've noticed is that the NAvBar is not visible:
[image: NavBar not visible]

The strange thing is that (when running with Chrome), I can see and interact with the NavBar
[image]

I've created a fresh project to make sure that none of the changes I made were responsible, "out of the box" I see the same behavior.

The following NuGet packages are installed in the project:

```
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="DanielSnowden.CommonLibrary" version="1.0.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.16.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

All packages appear to be up to data as I can't see any updates. I've tried viewing the website (through IIS local) in both Chrome and Edge. My Visual Studio version is 2017 (Community) and I'm running on a Windows 10 host.

I've tried to research the issue, but can't seem to find much information. However, I suspect that (as usual) I'm overlooking something perfectly obvious.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to say that in the second image that you posted, you are not able to see the NavBar ? If so, move the Developer Tools window to the right to see the NavBar content. 
As in the second image you have posted, it has switched to Mobile View because of Bootstrap styling.

Comment: In the second image I was able to see the NavBar. I didn't realise that I was viewing in mobile view and that the NavBar was a feature of the mobile view. Thanks, that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The NavBar is a feature only visible in the mobile layout.
Chrome provides the ability to simulate viewing on a number of different mobile devices. When inspecting elements, Chrome was defaulting to one of these devices.